# Hide rows in excel workbook excluding cell color - vba macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have the macro that will hide the rows with specific cell color, but i need the other way around.
Hide all the rows in entire workbook excluding specific colors.

```
Sub Hiderows()
Dim r As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Range("A7").Select
Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    For Each r In Selection
        If r.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 124, 128) Or r.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 163) Then
            r.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next
Range("A7").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Note: - The <> sign is not working here.
      - Also is there any way, as i can speedup the execution

Thanks,

Comment: Use your `<>` but change your `OR` to an `AND`. `If r.Interior.Color <> RGB(255, 124, 128) AND r.Interior.Color <> RGB(255, 255, 163) Then`

Comment: @JNevill - Its not working. Again hiding all rows.

Comment: Another approach without transforming your condition is to add an Else clause to your if.  Make the statement in the new 'else' clause be r.EntireRowHidden = True.  And then modify your prior code to r.EntireRowHidden = False.  So, rows with the colors will not be hidden, otherwise they will be hidden.

Comment: @Ryan B - I tried with this(else, elseif), also with multiple if's - still its not working.

Comment: Then the problem isn't your logical statement.  I'd start with make sure your color definitions are correct w/ what's in the sheet.

Comment: color definitions are correct, as it is working for hiding rows with these colors. but i am trying to exclude these colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, i see the problem now.

The object is to check multiple cells in a row, hiding that row if it doesn't have a color.  But if Cell B8 has the target color... what happens if A8 doesn't?  A8 triggers the logic and hides the row.  Whoops.

Give this a try.  It reads the whole row checking for the color and, once found, stops reading that row and processes the hide logic, and then moves on to the next row:

```
Sub Hiderows()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim hasColor As Boolean
    hasColor = False

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Range("A7").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
        For Each r In Selection.Rows
            For Each c In r.Columns
                If c.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 124, 128) Or c.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 163) Then
                    hasColor = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next

            r.EntireRow.Hidden = Not hasColor
            hasColor = False
        Next
    Range("A7").Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: @Ryaan B - its working fine :). Can i apply the same to entire workbook without any changes?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite know what you mean.  It will certainly run on whatever sheet is the active sheet.  Otherwise, this macro doesn't modify any data so you should be able to apply it anywhere without causing trouble.  Of course I always recommend working on a copy of your workbooks when testing out code from the web.  It's very difficult for me to make promises without knowing exactly what the rest of your environment looks like.

Comment: I wanted to apply the same macro on all worksheets within the same workbook, so just modified the code with another for loop; dim ws as Worksheet -> for each ws in Worksheets.